# How to get sender of pending transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, etherscan, web3.py

First I wanted to listen on a specific account address and found out I couldn't.

My solution was to listen to all transactions using `web3.subscribe("logs")` but I wonder if I can get the sender (or decode the data) of the transaction without getting the transaction's receipt.

It works if after receiving an event I get the receipt but the thing is there is a lot of transactions and I get a too many requests from my node.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The sender was in the second element of the topics array. I used `web3.decodeParameter('address', topics[1])` and successfully got the sender